# How can I print entire content in one page with no page breaks anywhere?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, pdf, puppeteer

I am trying to save a page via `puppeteer` and thus wanted to save the entire page in dynamically height adjustable PDF. My CSS is currently

```
@media print {

html{
    height: auto;
    background-color: #f7f7f4;
    page-break-inside : avoid;
}
```

But this causes page breaks when i use `Save as PDF` using chrome.

Is there any way to avoid it, Also for the same problem, Can it be solved using `puppeteer` if it's not possible on the client side?